# How to fix Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: arrays, object, php

I am getting the error: Trying to get property of non-object.  I'm all out of ideas as to why I am getting this error.  The error is for this line: `$results = $quotes->return;`  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.  Code is below.

```
public function ajax_get_chart_litecoin() {

    $quotes = $this->rest->get('api/2/ltc_usd/trades/fetch');


    $series_data = array();

    $results = $quotes->return;

    foreach ($results as $quote)
    {
      $series_tmp = array(
        'date'      =>  $quote->date,
        'price'     =>  $quote->price
      );

      $series_data[] = $series_tmp;
    }

    $series_data = array_slice($series_data, 0, 10);


    return json_encode($series_data);
  }
```

Comment: Did you try something like $quotes['return']? vardump $quotes and see what it gives.

Comment: use isset($quotes->return)

Comment: @hrnrgv it returned me bool(false)

Comment: after I do either of the above recommendations I get the following error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for this line: foreach ($results as $quote)

Comment: So you say $quotes does not contain anything?

Comment: yea I guess so but I don't understand that because im using the same exact code to put info from an API on a separate view and it works fine, but its not working on this page

Answer (score 0):

'Trying to get property of non-object' probably means exactly what it says. Your `$quotes` (A.K.A. object wanna-be) is not object. `null` Maybe? Just put `var_dump($quotes); die;` after your first line of function's body and you will find it out.